# Is there a template for this thesis style?

Tags: templates, thesis

I have to write a thesis paper this year, and I really like the look of [this example thesis](https://www.lucaversari.it/masters/thesis.pdf). I have come across it numerous times, so was wondering if there exists a template for it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the author of that thesis?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A well-intentioned advice: Do not use  templates for a thesis unless you are willing to fully read its documentation. You may not be aware of all kind of predefined strcutures in there. It may seem to be less work in the beginning, but (at least for me) it turned out to be best to start with `\documentclass{book}` and start from scratch.

Comment: I have not, wasn't sure if that was a common thing to do

Comment: @Roland makes sense I suppose.

Comment: Related maybe: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tesi-di-laurea-universita-di-pisa/rwdcqtqwftpg